# X-Frame-Options Enabling on GoDaddy

Tags: godaddy, http-headers

I am currently developing a website which runs on a GoDaddy Windows with Plesk hosting option.  I am doing this as an experimental/learning site so I am trying to be as security conscious as possible to get into the habit.  I have since used OWASP Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) to scan my site and it came up with a couple of vulnerabilities.  The first and highest priority is that I don't have X-Frame-Options set.  I am super new to this so I am wondering how to configure these to be sent as I understand they need to be sent from the server.  I may need to set them in my client but as of yet I am uncertain.  I am using Angular 4 to create a single-page application.

Answer (score 1):

You're running on Windows, which makes it likely that you're using IIS. Assuming this is the case, this post on StackOverflow has a discussion on how to set the X-Frame-Options header properly (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316781/x-frame-options-not-working-iis-web-config).

In short, it states that:

"An easy work around is to set the headers manually using:"

`Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");`

In the lesser likely case that you're running on Apache, you can find the information you need here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092154/x-frame-options-on-apache